# \hphantom* vs \hphantom: Spacing doesn't line up

Tags: spacing, phantom

I assumed the asterisk for phantom-type commands disabled the phantom command.
What is actually happening?

(Why don't the `a` characters line up?)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\hphantom*{ipsem} a\\
\hphantom{ipsem}  a
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `*`-variant for `\hphantom`. Besides, `\hphantom` doesn't start a paragraph. So you get an empty line (containing a phantom asterisk), then a new line with normal indentation, “ipsem a” on the line; then a new line (without indentation), a phantom “ipsem”, a space and an “a”.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}

The wrong one (note the empty line)

\hphantom*{ipsem} a\\
\hphantom{ipsem}  a

Control:

\hbox{*}
ipsem a\\
ipsem a

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh. Foolish me >.<